# How to loop through an array to find the closest distance?

Tags: java, loops, distance

I'm stuck trying to figure out how to loop through an array of zip codes and find the closest zip code to a target. The zip codes also contain their latitude and longitude which is used to calculate the distance to the target. I need figure out how to loop through the array storing the closest distance and then returning the zip code of the closest one. Any help would be great because I've tried everything I can think of.

```
 * Finds and returns the zip code of a postal zone in the collection
 * whose centroid is closest to a given location. 
 * 
 * @param   target    the target location.
 * 
 * @return  returns zipCode of the postal zone whose centroid is closest;
 *          returns COLLECTION_EMPTY if no zones are in the collection.
 */
public String findClosestZone(Location target)
{
    int counter = 0;
    String closeZip = COLLECTION_EMPTY;
    double closestDistance = 100.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < this.zoneCount; i++)
    {
        if (this.zones[i].getZoneLocation()
            .calcDistance(target) < closestDistance)
        {
            closeZip = this.zones[i].getZoneZipCode();
            closestDistance = this.zones[i]
            .getZoneLocation().calcDistance(target);
            counter++;
            return closeZip;
        }
    }
    return closeZip;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Here, take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/about).  There is no question here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html):

```
A method returns to the code that invoked it when it

1. completes all the statements in the method,
2. reaches a return statement, or
3. throws an exception,
whichever occurs first.
```

It means that your code finishes its work after the first iteration. As far as I understand you want to find the closest one among array of zones.
I guess you don't need `return` inside loop. Please comment or delete it .

```
public String findClosestZone(Location target)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        String closeZip = COLLECTION_EMPTY;
        double closestDistance = 100.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < this.zoneCount; i++)
        {
            if (this.zones[i].getZoneLocation().calcDistance(target) < closestDistance)
            {
                closeZip = this.zones[i].getZoneZipCode();
                closestDistance = this.zones[i].getZoneLocation().calcDistance(target);
                counter++;
                // return closeZip;
            }
        }
        return closeZip;
    }
```

Comment: The return is there to return the zip code that is closest to the target location.

Comment: in fact it returns not the closest, but the first one. You need to loop  through the array and find the closest one? Correct?

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: ok, could you please try without inner return?

Comment: Sure. Wow, it worked. I'm not understanding why but that's great. Thanks!